# I can't get a record when using COUNT in php

Tags: php, mysql, count

i have 2 tables like this

tbl_inbox
-SenderNumber
-Message

tbl_report
-Number
-Name
-Count

actually i want to show how many times these numbers appear in table count,
i have try this code,but didn't show anything.
this my code :

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT count(SenderNumber) as num FROM tbl_inbox WHERE SenderNumber = ".$data['Number']"");  
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($count);  
$countresult = $result['num'];
```

Comment: why u have a . in ".$data['Number']"??. Correct it

Comment: Why did you show us `tbl_report` if your query doesn't use it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your concatenation is incorrect, it should be

```
...WHERE SenderNumber = ".$data['Number']);
```

Secondly, instead of using `count()` you can use `mysql_num_rows()`

```
echo mysql_num_rows($count); //Returns row count
```

> Note: `mysql_()` is deprecated, consider using [`mysqli_()`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
>   instead

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` will always return 1 for this query. If you change the query to `select *`, it's much less efficient since it has to download all the resulting rows.

Comment: but, before using mysql_num_rows() you need to fetch rows.

Comment: @Barmar if he is using `count()` than yes, only 1 will be returned, also, the code he provided, concatenation was the only issue I saw, other than that, `mysql_num_rows` was an optional method I provided him

Comment: Why recommend a bad option when he's already using the better option?

Comment: @Barmar again, I first solved his issue, and than I threw an option, this can be handy when user cannot change the query but he may like to get number of rows..

Comment: @Mr.Alien, If you want to use `mysql_num_rows()`, then you have have to use `select *` or `select COLUMN_NAME` which will take more time in compare to `count(COLUMN_NAME)`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct sql:

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT count(SenderNumber) as num FROM tbl_inbox WHERE SenderNumber = ".$data['Number']);
```